# Laravel 3 - Extending from a controller that extends the Base controller

Tags: php, oop, laravel

Why do I get a

```
Class 'Search_Controller' not found
```

when doing this:

```
class Snippets_Controller extends Search_Controller {

public $restful = true;

public function get_index()
{
    $snippets = Snippet::all();
    $categories = Categorie::all();

    return View::make('snippet.index')->with(array(
        'snippets' => $snippets,
        'categories' => $categories,
        'active_categorie' => Session::get('active_categorie_id')
        )
    );
}
```

The Search Controller:

```
class Search_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    protected static function build_html_for_search_results($search_results)
    {
...
```

Comment: maybe wrong filename for Search_Controller?

Comment: The `Search_Controller` will need to be included within the `Snippets_Controller` file if you don't have an autoloader

Comment: I assume Laravel does the autoloading for the whole controller folder??

Comment: Laravel 3 does not autoload the controllers directory as standard. The base controller created will need to be added to Laravels autoloader within `start.php`. Nico's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should autoload this in you application start.php folder.
If you open that file, and you search for "Base_Controller", you will see something like this:

```
Autoloader::map(array(
    'Base_Controller'       => path('app').'controllers/base.php'
));
```

The only thing you have to do is add the search controller there:

```
Autoloader::map(array(
    'Base_Controller'       => path('app').'controllers/base.php',
    'Search_Controller'     => path('app').'controllers/search.php'
));
```

And that should do the trick.

Laravel loads controllers based on the name that's requested, and it doesn't autload any of the controllers, as it would be a waste of time for 90% of the controllers.